# Winforms Designer Incompatible with Older Versions

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015, autoscalemode

I recently got a new computer and a copy of Visual Studios 2015. I opened some older projects (C#, winform, VS2010) and can edit the code just fine. However any changes to the UI in the designer, causes the entire UI to or not show part of the screen or glitch out.

Has any one ever experienced these issues? If so, how do I fix i?

Edit: 
I discovered the issue has to do with the AutoScaleMode attribute of my project's form.

Comment: I believe that VS 2010 solutions need to be upgraded before they can opened in VS 2013 and later (including 2015). You should not be able to open your form until you upgrade. If, however, you managed to do it somehow, using 3rd party controls may be causing it.

Comment: how do you upgrade them?

Comment: Just open a solution in VS 2015, it will prompt to be upgraded. Choose wisely as you cannot go back to 2010 after the upgrade.

Comment: I did this originally and just now, and it indicated no issues upgrading either time.

Comment: Are you using any custom or 3rd party UI components on the form?

Comment: None, just the items from the toolbox

Comment: Well, then the only way to find out is if you posted your project, I could then open it in my environment and see if it works. Strip out all the private stuff if you want, and make sure it still misbehaves.

Comment: I discovered the issue. On my form there is a property called autoscale which seems to be the issue. If i open my designer in notepad++ and change autoscale to None from Font, it works, but the UI on the designer scrunches together really close but displays right when i run the program. The scrunching is not very desirable though :/

Comment: Please add screenshots to your question, to help explain what you mean.

Comment: @Neolisk _"I believe that VS 2010 solutions need to be upgraded before they can opened in VS 2013"_ - incorrect.  One merely needs to have VS2010 SP1 installed. With that installed, VS2010+ share a unified project structure without requiring upgrade (most things anyway).  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh266747%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @Micky: Too late, I already upgraded all my solutions to 2013/2015. :)

Comment: @Neolisk check the Original Post for screencaps.

Comment: Your `before` version looks fine. Why did you decide to change anything?

Comment: @Neolisk see what happens when I go before altering the UI to altering the UI (added a button). Its in the main post.

Comment: My proposal stands, wrap up your project, pack into a zip file and share a link here. Unless it's too private / NDA etc. I will try to do same and see what happens / how to remedy.

Comment: There is an NDA on the sourcecode that I can't violate. I'll see if i can recreate this with another application.

Comment: Yes, I was going to suggest exactly that. Try to use as few controls on the form as possible, strip out all business logic. I.e. just leave designer code. See if it still happens, chance is you may be able to figure it out yourself by then, just make sure what's left is as simple as possible. It's calling making a [reduced test case](https://css-tricks.com/reduced-test-cases/) btw.

Comment: @Neolisk I removed all the code in our NDA and left a UI shell for you to look at. The error still occurs when you add onto the UI with the designer. How should I send you this zip?

Comment: Public hosting, google drive with link or email me @gmail.com - you decide.

Comment: @Neolisk emailed you it.

Comment: If you guys discover anything, please share - I have the same problem in a project that I'm working on. Thanks!

Comment: @IliaKoulikov Will do, having same issues.

Comment: @IliaKoulikov check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up setting the form's autoscalemode to none. Doing that seemed to take care of my issues. I had to reorganize my UI but that was worth having the ability to use the designer again.

Comment: @Neolisk thanks for all your assistance, I greatly appreciate it.